# Interactive character sheets?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-sheets

Looking for a decent alternative to the DDI Builder, ideally a free browser version. Currently using [myth weavers](http://www.myth-weavers.com/sheetindex.php) and it's decent, but I'm just a guy that likes options.

I've seen a [similar thread](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7980/is-there-an-interactive-character-sheet-for-dungeons-dragons-4e), but it's 2yrs old. I looked at a few of the options but found mostly PDF stuff. Currently playing on roll20, so I like the idea of being able to share a link back and forth with the DM.

Thanks.

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate. If none of the answers on the question provide assistance, the correct action is indeed to earn reputation and provide a bounty on it. Take a look at our [tour] for an idea of how we work.

Comment: I would've happily commented on the old question, but I don't have the rep for that. For clarification, would the proper course have been to 'answer' that question (adding in my MW link as gravy, I suppose) with a request for new information? Thanks.

Comment: @soopadoopa I have created a bounty for you.  Ironic that names are so similiar for the question being asked

Comment: @soopadoopa Not that you need to do it this time, since it's been bountied, but in the future you could edit an answer or the question to bump it to the front page again (as long as it's actually a good and constructive edit). Answers should only be used to answer the question, so that would be misusing them. It seems you're thinking of this place as being like a forum, and it really isn't. You should check our [about] page to see how this place works, and the [help] if you need to know anything more. When you have 20 reputation, you can [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).